# Bad vechicle travel times predictions using Artificial Neural Networks at Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network, regression

I Want to predict travel times of vehicles using Artificial Neural Networks through Matlab. My input data are: *days, hours, time period*.

I want to predict travel times. When I use as training data a sample of 30 days (hour by hour) to predict for one day (hour by hour) I have really bad predictions.

On the contrary, when I use 2 days (hour by hour) data I have better predictions. I have tried 2,3,4... days and various architectures and the Regression never exceeds 0.67. This means that I haven't a good model. What is my wrong? The code is the following:

```
%% Read the xlsx
insertdata = xlsread('input4.xlsx');
testdata = xlsread('test.xlsx');
% input data
px=insertdata(:,2:4);
p=px';
% target data
tx=insertdata(:,1);
t=tx';
% test data
ptestx=testdata(:,2:4);
ptest=ptestx';
ptesty=testdata(:,1);
ptesy=ptesty';
[pn,minp,maxp,tn,mint,maxt]=premnmx(p,t); %Normalize Data [-1, 1]
NodeNum1 = 20;
NodeNum2 = 10;
TypeNum = 1; % output vector dimensions
TF1 = 'tansig'; TF2 = 'tansig'; TF3 = 'tansig';
net=newff(minmax(pn),[NodeNum1,NodeNum2,TypeNum],{TF1 TF2 TF3},'traingdx');
%Creat network 'traingdm'
net.trainParam.show=50;
net.trainParam.epochs=1000; 
net.trainParam.goal=1e-7;
net.trainParam.lr=0.01; 
net=train(net,pn,tn);
```

Comment: Can you post  a sample of your data? And what is 0.67?

Comment: @Fernando, 0.67 is Regression index. It should be about 0.99 (almost 1) in order to be sure that I have a good model. My data are: Time in seconds, Day, Time Period and Hour at the following columns respectively.
25 1 1 1
22 1 1 2
22 1 1 3
20 1 1 4
19 1 1 5
19 1 1 6
30 1 1 7
19 1 1 8
28 1 2 9
33 1 2 10
34 1 2 11
109 1 2 12
73 1 2 13
112 1 2 14
25 1 2 15
119 1 3 16
27 1 3 17
101 1 3 18
37 1 3 19
112 1 3 20
50 1 3 21
25 1 4 22
25 1 4 23
30 1 4 24
19 2 1 25
17 2 1 26
16 2 1 27

Comment: The code is: 
`% input data
px=insertdata(:,2:4)
p=px'
% target data
tx=insertdata(:,1)
t=tx'
% test data
ptestx=testdata(:,2:4)
ptest=ptestx'
ptesty=testdata(:,1)
ptesy=ptesty'
[pn,minp,maxp,tn,mint,maxt]=premnmx(p,t) %Normalize Data
NodeNum1 = 20
NodeNum2 = 10
TypeNum = 1; % output vector dimensions
TF1 = 'tansig'; TF2 = 'tansig'; TF3 = 'tansig'
net=newff(minmax(pn),[NodeNum1,NodeNum2,TypeNum],{TF1 TF2 TF3},'traingdx')
%Creat network 'traingdm'
net.trainParam.show=50
net.trainParam.epochs=1000 
net.trainParam.goal=1e-7
net.trainParam.lr=0.01 
net=train(net,pn,tn)`

Comment: Well, I don't know matlab, can you post the train and test data? It seems you never used `ptest`. And what exactly is 0.67? R2 index?

Comment: No, it is not R2, it's just R. The following figure is produced automatically by matlab.  [link](http://imgur.com/a/QJejE)

Comment: @Fernando at the follow link I have my [train and test data](http://imgur.com/a/81R0t)